# Can we use the measurability definition on a set which is not supposed measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$ with $m^*(E)>0$. Prove that for each > $\alpha\in]0,1[$, there exist an open interval $I$ so that $$m^*(E\cap I)\geq \alpha m^*(I).$$

*Notation: Here $m^*$ is the exterior mesure of Lebesgue*.

**In the correction it's written:**

$E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z} E\cap [n-1,n]$, therefore $$m^*(E)\leq\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}m^*\left(E\cap [n-1,n]\right).$$

Moreover, we can suppose $E$ bounded, therefore $m^*(E)$ is finite.

**Question 1:** *Why can we suppose $E$ bounded ? If it's not bounded it's obvious ?*

If $\alpha\in]0,1[$, there exist an open set $O\supset E$ such that $$m^*(E)\geq m(O)-(1-\alpha)m^*(E)\geq \alpha m(O).$$

**Question 2:** *Here is my problem, if $E$ would be mesurable I would agree, but here $E$ is not supposed mesurable, that's why I don't understand why there exist ans open $O\supset E$ such that $m^*(E)+\varepsilon\geq m(O)$. Here the $\varepsilon=(1-\alpha)m^*(E)$.*

Comment: The $m^\ast(E)$ is defined for all $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, this implies nothing about $E$ being measurable.

Comment: What is your exact definition of $m^\ast$? This probably implies existence of $O$.

Comment: it's $$m^*(E)=\inf \sum_{i=1}^\infty |Q_i|$$ where $E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i$ and $Q_i$ are closed cube. (Other question, in this definition, we can also take open cubes no ?)